# type 'DateTime' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast

Tags: flutter, drift

I don't quite understand what the problem is, the field in the local database is of the DateTime type and I pass the same type

method fromJson, the error is here:

```
dateTimeCreateToken:
          serializer.fromJson<DateTime>(json['dateTimeCreateToken']),
```

column from table:

```
 DateTimeColumn get dateTimeCreateToken => dateTime()();
```

the code where I give it to the FromJSON method:

```
dateTimeCreateToken:
              dateNow.add(Duration(seconds: response.data["expires_in"])),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `json['dateTimeCreateToken']` type is **int**. I thing it is **millisecondsEpoch** or **microsecondsEpoch**. Please try this.

```dart
void main() async {
  var epoch = 1650012545317;
  var datetime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(epoch);
  
  print(datetime);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means that the value json['dateTimeCreateToken'] is of type 'int; and Dart is trying to convert an 'int' Type into a DateTime Type and so it is throwing an error.